# HP 6L with JetDirect prints single line of garbage

Tags: windows-xp, printer, network-printer, hp-laserjet

I added an HP 6L with JetDirect (network printer) to Windows XP as a local printer and created a standard TCP/IP port with the IP address of the printer. I used HP > HP LaserJet 6L as the driver.

When I try to print a test page, I get one line of garbage and the rest of the page is blank. It keeps printing one line of garbage on each sheet until the paper runs out.

What else can I try?

Comment: Does the printer print it internal test page(s) and network configuration pages OK?

Comment: You mean if I push the "test" button on the Jet Direct? I have other computers on the network that can use this printer just fine, including another XP box. I matched the settings on the other Windows XP box and that computer prints correctly while this one doesn't- which is why I'm confused. I'm sure there's some subtle setting that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unplugging the printer and the JetDirect and leaving them unplugged for a couple hours seems to have resolved the problem.